# Ramsey number for two graphs

Tags: graph-theory, definition, ramsey-theory

Given R(G, H) = n, we have the minimum number such that $K_n$ will always contain G in one color OR H in the other. Is this definition correct? I ask because I'm very confused about the particular wording. For example, if my definition is correct then there should exist a$K_{n-1}$ such that G is not present in one color AND H is not present in the other color.

Am I right so far?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, though for greater clarity I would make the quantification over colorings explicit:

If $R(G,H)=n$ then ***every*** coloring of the ***edges*** of $K_n$ with ***two*** colors, call them blue and red, will either contain a blue copy of $G$ or a red copy of $H$. Also, since $n$ in minimum, there exists a blue-red coloring of the edges of $K_{n-1}$ containing no blue $G$ and no red $H.$

A trivial example: $R(K_2,K_3)=3.$ Thus, if each edge of the triangle $K_3$ is colored blue or red, there must be either a blue edge or a red triangle. (Swapping the roles of the colors, there must be a red edge or a blue triangle. So we could also say: either there is a blue triangle, or there is a red triangle, or there are edges of both colors.) On the other hand, we can color $K_2$ so that there is neither a blue triangle nor a red edge. To accomplish that, we color the single edge blue.

Less trivial examples: $R(K_3,K_3)=6$ and $R(K_3,K_4)=9$ and $R(P_5,K_{1,3})=5.$